# How much must the Sun's radiation be reduced to offset global warming?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation, atmospheric-science, estimation, geophysics

About 70 % of earth is covered with clouds and the rate of atmospheric water vapor is increasing. Also the warming of the oceans will most probably cause more and deeper low pressures and increased covering. This would decrease the insolation and thereby my question:

> How much must the sun's radiation be reduced to offset global warming of today?

Comment: By about 3 Watt/m^2

Comment: @CountIblis: How come?

Comment: See the Total column in the table at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiative_forcing.

Comment: Thanks, both of you!